# Wamp with php 7 net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error

Tags: php, css, certificate, wamp

Today I installed new Wampserver with php7 support. None of my projects load js and css now..

I get `net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` in the console.

Googled as much as I can, found some solutions, but none of the helped me..

I tried:

1. Test in chrome and firefox.. both not working
2. added `curl.cainfo` url to the certification in php.ini
3. set `session.use_only_cookies = 1` and `session.use_strict_mode = 1` in php.ini.
4. Tried clearing cookies in chrome settings.

These steps seem to fix most of the problems for other people... not me... What else can I do?

Comment: Do you have an antivirus?

Comment: I dont have any antivirus installed

Comment: Check that your CSS and JS files are correctly included in your page.

Comment: it worsks fine with in other systems

Comment: In my case all sites even phpMyAdmin suddenly got ERR_CONNECTION_RESET and it was caused by Kaspersky Network Attack Blocker